# Deriving the limit of a sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, derivatives

Consider a function $\mu:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ differentiable at $0$. Now, consider the sequence
$$
\sqrt{n}(\mu(\frac{h}{\sqrt{n}})-\mu(0))
$$
for $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $h \in \mathbb{R}$. Could you help me to show that 
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sqrt{n}(\mu(\frac{h}{\sqrt{n}})-\mu(0))=h\mu'(0)
$$
where $\mu'(0)$ is the derivative of $\mu(\cdot)$ at $0$?

I think it is related with the definition of derivative but I don't know how to formally deal with the presence of $h$ inside $\mu$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
\mu'(0)=
\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\mu(t)-\mu(0)}{t}=\lim_{n\to\infty}{n(\mu(1/n)-\mu(0))}=
\lim_{n\to\infty}{\sqrt n(\mu(\frac{1}{\sqrt n})-\mu(0))}=
\lim_{n\to\infty}{\frac{\sqrt n}{h}(\mu(\frac{h}{\sqrt n})-\mu(0))}
$$
Supposing $h\ne 0$. Those changes of variable are allowed since we can approximate the limit however we please, supposing its existence, and get the same result. To toy inside the $\mu$ expression continuity of $\mu$ in $0$ in also needed. Note that both the existence of the limit and the continuity of the function are given since $\mu$ is derivable and thus continuous in $0$.

From here, we can take the h out of the limit and pass it to the left side of the equality, arriving to:
$$
h\mu'(0)=\lim_{n\to\infty}{\sqrt n(\mu(\frac{h}{\sqrt n})-\mu(0))}
$$
In the case $h=0$, the equality is trivial, since:
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}{\sqrt n(\mu(\frac{0}{\sqrt n})-\mu(0))}= \lim_{n\to\infty}{\sqrt n(\mu(0)-\mu(0))}=\lim_{n\to\infty}0=0\cdot\mu'(0)
$$

Comment: Thanks! I have a question: I agree that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sqrt{n}(\mu(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}})-\mu(0))=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{\sqrt{n}}{h}(h\mu(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}})-\mu(0))$. But why $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{\sqrt{n}}{h}(h\mu(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}})-\mu(0))=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{\sqrt{n}}{h}(\mu(\frac{h}{\sqrt{n}})-\mu(0))$? $\mu$ is not linear

Comment: @user299158 I am not making use of linearity, but merely noting that $\lim_n\to\inf \frac{1}{n} = \lim_n\to\inf \frac{h}{n} = 0$. Similarly, $n$ and $n/h$ have the same character inside a limit.

Comment: Thanks, I don't understand your notation in the comment

Comment: I think there was a typo in @Jsevillamol's comment, the point is that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{h}{\sqrt{n}} = 0$ since $h$ is constant, hence $\lim_{n\to\infty} \mu(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}) = \lim_{n\to\infty} \mu(\frac{h}{\sqrt{n}})$ since $\mu$ is differentiable, and hence continuous, at $0$.

Comment: Ok, thanks to all

Comment: One should really be careful here though, this answer is not fully complete without saying that we are only allowed to do this change of variables because $\mu$ is differentiable, and hence continuous at $0$.

Comment: Ok, thanks. The question is open again